# Angular CanActivate With Login Dialog

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable, angular-material2

I have an `AuthGuard` in which I want to use a login `material2` dialog with it.  So before `canActivate` returns, the login dialog is shown and if the login is successful then the dialog returns `true` so then `canActivate` returns `true` as well.  If the login is not successful, then the dialog does not return anything and tries again.

I have already implemented the dialog in a `component` and its working fine,  I'm looking for help on how to integrate it with the `canActivate` guard.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, 
            private dialog: MatDialog,
            private router: Router) {}

    successfulLogin: boolean;

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

       // Open the Dialog
       let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialog, {
            width: '450px',
            data: { success: this.successfulLogin }
        });

        // NEED HELP HERE, UNSURE HOW TO RETURN
        return dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result =>{
            return result;
        })
    }
}
```

The `result` from the `subscribe` is returning `true` but I am unsure about the logic on how to return from `canActivate` properly.  The code above gives the following error statement.

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'boolean |
>   Observable | Promise'.   Type 'Subscription' is not
>   assignable to type 'Promise'.
>       Property 'then' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toPromise` method instead

```
return dialogRef.afterClosed().toPromise().then(result =>{
    return result ? true : false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no reason to use a Promise there, if you don't want to.

The problem you're facing is that you're actually returning your `Subscription` (i.e.: the result of calling `.subscribe(...)` on your `Observable`) instead of the `Observable` itself!

Simply use:

```js
return dialogRef.afterClosed();
```

Or better yet, if `result` isn't actually a `boolean`:

```js
return dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(result => !!result);
```